# Detect when a screenshot is taken and display a message - Android .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

I'm working on an application for Android using .NET MAUI. I want to detect when a screenshot is taken and display a message on the screen (in a label). Also run a process in the background to retrieve the screenshot.

I managed to retrieve the screenshots taken, but I'm struggling with the detection part. I would appreciate any help or guidance to how detect when a screenshot is taken and update the label text with the screenshot file name.

Comment: You can't really detect them, at least not all of them. Whichever method you choose can be overcome with something as similar as taking a photo of the screen. Or casting your screen to another device and screenshotting on there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply David. I don't want to block taking screenshot. The idea is to take a screenshot of the app and then update the label text with "screenshot taken successfully - [FileName]". Then I will have another process to retrieve the screenshot and send it to the support team.

Comment: Then just let the user take a screenshot and they can choose the file to upload.

Comment: Unfortunately for some reasons we can't go with this approach :/
It is not possible to detect when a screenshot is taken?

Comment: Do you mean [Screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/screenshot?view=net-maui-8.0) ?